# i want to match two dataframe columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a two data frame df1 (35k record) and df2(100k records). In df1['col1'] and df2['col3'] i have unique id's. I want to match df1['col1'] with df2['col3']. If they match, I want to update df1 with one more column say df1['Match'] with value true and if not match, update with False value. I want to map this TRUE and False value against Matching and non-matching record only.

I am using `.isin()`function, I am getting the correct match and not match count but not able to map them correctly.

```
Match = df1['col1'].isin(df2['col3'])
df1['match'] = Match
```

I have also used merge function using by passing the parameter `how=right`but did not get the results.

Comment: What do you mean by not mapping correctly? Using your syntax, `df1['match'] = df1['col1'].isin(df2['col3'])` seems to work for your described goal. Rows of `df1` whose `col1` value is found in `df2['col3']` will be True, otherwise False.

Comment: @kentwait After doing `df1['match'] = Match`, if I have 10  records matching. then in df1 it is just getting updated in serial wise but not to the exact record it is matching.

Comment: The number of rows returned by `df1['col1'].isin(df2['col3'])` is equal to the number of rows of `df1` regardless of how many matching "True" records found. You can try @crazyGamer answer but your code should work fine. Maybe something else is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do as follows:

```
df1['Match'] = df1['col1'].isin(df2['col3'])
```

For instance:

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
data2 = [2,3,5]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['a'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2,columns=['c'])
print (df1)
print (df2)
df1['Match'] = df1['a'].isin(df2['c']) # if matches it returns True else False
print (df1)
```

Output:

```
  a
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5

   c
0  2
1  3
2  5

   a  Match
0  1  False
1  2   True
2  3   True
3  4  False
4  5   True
```

Comment: This is the same as what the OP posted without the intervening variable. There must be something else the OP is encountering.

Comment: @Ranjith - This is also not working..as in you example all the values are in sorted order, if it is not sorted it will not work..the code that you share is what I am already doing.plz check my code

Answer (score 0):

Use [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) indexing:

```
df1['Match'] = False
df1.loc[df1['col1'].isin(df2['col3']), 'Match'] = True
```

Comment: @crazyGamer- thanks it work for me.. Can i also map `df2['col3']` value for True cases?

Comment: Yes, you can repeat this pattern for `df2` and `col3`. How it work is the first line creates a new column and sets all values to False. The second line indexes the rows using a boolean Series, and sets those rows to True.